# Titanium eventslistener for an array of ListSection

Tags: android, events, titanium, appcelerator, addeventlistener

I have question in appcelerator, Titanium: How do I generalize the `EventListener` dynamically? In my project, I have an array of `listSection` which was dynamically created. The question is that, how do I create an events listener which would allow the whole `listView` sharing the same behavior of events?

```
var sections = [];

var SectionOne = Ti.UI.createListSection({
        headerTitle : "Section one"
    });
var SectionTwo = Ti.UI.createListSection({
        headerTitle : "Section two"
    });
var SectionThree = Ti.UI.createListSection({
        headerTitle : "Section three"
    });

sections.push(SectionOne);
sections.push(SectionTwo);
sections.push(SectionThree);

/*problem below*/
listView.addEventListener('itemclick', function(e) {
    for (var sec in sections) {
        var item = sections[sec].getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
        if (item.properties.accessoryType == Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_NONE) {
            audioPlayer.start();
            item.properties.accessoryType = Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_CHECKMARK;
            item.properties.color = 'red';
            Ti.API.info('e.index: ' + e.itemIndex);
        } else {
            audioPlayer.stop();
            item.properties.accessoryType = Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_NONE;
            item.properties.color = 'black';
        }
        sections[sec].updateItemAt(e.itemIndex, item);
    }
});
win.add(listView);
```

Comment: still dont understand this question or what the problem is here

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's help you if you want to get Section Index :

```
listView.addEventListener('itemclick', function(e) {

    alert("SectionID" + data.sessions[e.sectionIndex].Session_Name);
});
```